# Reactjs does not load the text font

Tags: reactjs, font-face, styled-components

I am using `React` with `Typescript` and `Styled-Component` and I am not able to upload a text font, only the font does **not load in the browser**. What I have is the following ...

**Fonts.ts:**

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';

export const SpotifyFont = css`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Spotify-Light';
        src: url('assets/fonts/Spotify/Spotify-Light.eot');
        src: url('assets/fonts/Spotify/Spotify-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('assets/fonts/Spotify/Spotify-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('assets/fonts/Spotify/Spotify-Light.woff') format('woff'),
            url('assets/fonts/Spotify/Spotify-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('assets/fonts/Spotify/Spotify-Light.svg#Spotify-Light') format('svg');
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: swap;
    }
`;
```

**GlobalStyle.ts:**

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import { SpotifyFont } from 'assets/styles/Fonts';
import { ResetLayout } from 'assets/styles/Reset';
import { Colors } from 'assets/styles/Colors';

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    ${SpotifyFont}
    ${ResetLayout}
    ${Colors}

    html {
        @media (max-width: 720px) {
            font-size: 87.5%;
        }

        @media (max-width: 1080px) {
            font-size: 93.75%;
        }
    }

    body {
        font-family: 'Spotify-Light' !important;
        color: var(--grey-dark-1);
        background-color: white;
    }
`;
```

The `path` is set to absolute in `tsconfig.json`, `"baseUrl": "src"` and `"include": ["src"]`.

[My Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0wHN.png)

[My Browser Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/katA4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up spending a good few hours researching different places and found the following solution:

1 - Create a **folder** called `types` in `src` **(To get better organized)**.

2 - Create a `d.ts` called `fonts.d.ts` and inside it insert the following code `snippet`:

```
declare module '* .eot';
declare module '* .ttf';
declare module '* .woff';
declare module '* .woff2';

declare module '* .svg' {
 // const content: React.FunctionComponent <React.SVGAttributes <SVGElement>>;
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

3 - Add the following code `snippet` to the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOption": {
  "baseUrl": "src",
   typeRoots ": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"]
},
"include": ["src/**/*"]
```

4- Now to finish and **not give the following error** in the `eslint` `"Parsing error: Invalid character"`, add the following code `snippet` in `.eslintrc.js`:

```
ignorePatterns: ['src/assets/fonts/*']
```

Now fonts can be imported smoothly in this way:

```
import FontNameEOT from 'assets/fonts/FONT_NAME/FONT_NAME.eot';
import FontNameTTF from 'assets/fonts/FONT_NAME/FONT_NAME.eot';
import FontNameWOFF2 from 'assets/fonts/FONT_NAME/FONT_NAME.eot';
import FontNameWOFF from 'assets/fonts/FONT_NAME/FONT_NAME.eot';

export const VAR_NAME = css`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FONT_NAME';
        font-weight: FONT_WEIGHT;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('${FontNameEOT}');
        src: url('${FontNameEOT}')    format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('${FontNameTTF}')    format('truetype'),
             url('${FontNameWOFF2}')  format('woff2'),
             url('${FontNameWOFF}')   format('woff');
    }
`;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your guidance; only one thing that I faced with your solution was the ==> fonts.d.t.s should be changed to fonts.d.ts